# Change of Variables formula for $\mu \circ f$ rather than $\mu \circ f^{-1}$ (pullback rather than pushforward)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory, change-of-variable

##### Change of Variables Formula

Here's the standard change of variables formula (notation and assumptions in the first comment) for a test function $\varphi:\mathsf{Y}\to[0, +\infty]$ and a pushforward measure $\mathbb{P}\circ f^{-1}$ by a measurable function $f$.
$$
\int_{\mathsf{Y}} \varphi \, d\mathbb{P}\circ f^{-1} = \int_{f^{-1}(\mathsf{Y})} \varphi\circ f \, d\mathbb{P}.
$$

##### Question

> Suppose rather than $P_f$ I have a distribution $\mathbb{P}\circ g$, for a function $g:\mathsf{Y}\to\Omega$. Does the change of variables formula still work?
> $$
> \int_{\mathsf{Y}} \varphi \,d \mathbb{P}\circ g = \int_{g(Y)} \varphi\circ g^{-1} \, d\mathbb{P}
> $$

Comment: Assumptions: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ be a measurable space. Consider a random variable $f:\Omega\to\mathsf{Y}$ that has distribution $P_f = \mathbb{P}\circ f^{-1}$ on $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$. Consider another measurable function $\varphi: \mathsf{Y}\to[0, +\infty]$, then $\varphi\circ f$ is also $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Comment: How do you define $P\circ g$?

Comment: Given a measurable subset $\mathsf{B}\subset \mathsf{Y}$ I define it as:
$$
(\mathbb{P}\circ g)(\mathsf{B}) = \mathbb{P}(g(\mathsf{B}))
$$

Comment: Have you tried to show that $P \circ g$ is at least a measure?

Comment: This is relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122704/pullback-measures

Comment: Sorry if my assumptions are incorrect... Students are usually annoyed by the $^{-1}$ in $\mu \circ f^{-1}$. I don't intend to prune you... but I'd like to suggest you to "open your mind for $^{-1}$" and also, that you try to give some meaning to what you want to do... What is $\mu(f(A))$??? IMO, it is very natural to give meaning to $\mu(f^{-1}(A))$. You are asking what is the probability of "hitting" $A$ through $f$.

Comment: @Euler_Salter: the issue is that $f(B)$ may not be measurable, even if $f$ is measurable.